# Youtube api get the channels from the Featured channels module

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

i want to get all the channel from the module `Featuring channel` of a YouTube channel ,with the API V3 of YouTube

I post a picture, you can see what is the module  `Featuring channel`

[image]

This is the module with all the YouTube channel.

I want to get this with the api but i can't find the information in the API. 
**Is it possible ?**

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3027950?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>There isn't option to grab the featured channel on the youtube api V3.
I think we also need to wait an update of the api v3.</del>

I finally found a solution with YouTube API V3 !

If you check the documentation of [Channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels?hl=fr) you can see the parameter : **brandingSettings**

The featured channels are in the brandingSettings results. All you need is the id for the YouTube channel, not the username. I made a tool to find the **Id of a channel** YouTube with the name.

http://martialdidit.github.io/YoutubeID/

For example, the channel is : **YouTubeHelp** -> id : **UCMDQxm7cUx3yXkfeHa5zJIQ**

So with this ID and the part : brandingSettings you are able to find the featured channels.

An exemple with [api's explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=brandingSettings&id=UCMDQxm7cUx3yXkfeHa5zJIQ&_h=6&)

The result :

```
  "brandingSettings": {
    "channel": {
     "title": "YouTube Help",
     "description": "Subscribe for tutorials, troubleshooting, and tips from the YouTube Help team! Check out the links below for more help.",
     "keywords": "youtube help tutorials \"youtube help\" Hilfe Ayuda Aide ヘルプ 도움 Ajuda",
     "moderateComments": true,
     "showRelatedChannels": true,
     "showBrowseView": true,
     "featuredChannelsTitle": "Featured Channels",
     "featuredChannelsUrls": [
      "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
      "UCUZHFZ9jIKrLroW8LcyJEQQ",
      "UCeNZlh03MyUkjRlLFpVQxsg",
      "UCkRfArvrzheW2E7b6SVT7vQ",
      "UCEN58iXQg82TXgsDCjWqIkg",
      "UCgNxLruwXS9fJNPztu5AVQA"
     ],
     "unsubscribedTrailer": "MjHDKJuPjLs",
     "profileColor": "#000000"
    },
```

If you check the table : `featuredChannelsUrls`

Each id is corresponding to a featured channel. Use the API V3 to find the name of the channels associate.

Comment: you are the youtube plugin master

Answer (score 1):

No. Upon checking the documentation, I don't think youtube api [V3](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/) lists options to grab list of featured videos.

However, version V2 had an option to get the [recently featured](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/youtube_api_appengine?csw=1) list. It has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

brandingSettings and featuredChannelsUrls are no longer retrievable via that V3 API. However... see channelSections in the API (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249896644#comment7)
python code to get to what you want:

```
channelID='UCaHx0T1LWrVKWF1XfWWLSuw'
channel=youtube.channelSections().list(
        part='snippet,contentDetails',
        channelId=ChannelID).execute()
for item in channel['items']:
    if item['snippet']['type']=='multiplechannels':
        Recommended_Channels=item['contentDetails']['channels']
```