# YouTube Preferred Channels Feed or API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm looking to programmatically discover the YouTube Preferred channels (Examples: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCiq_aAkP44mMpRx8VvQiF6w/channels?shelf_id=5204494150831773367&view=49 and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpXBkrx5YWAe8I9nbmLK_fA/channels?) but the channel pages with their AJAX lists is all I've found. Obviously it would be much easier to crawl an API or an RSS feed (or even a static HTML page!) and I've yet to find anything like that with each of the YouTube Preferred channel ids.

Am I missing something? Do these preferred channel lists really only exist in this one form?

Edit #1: I have tried to use the YouTube Data API to pull these "Preferred" channels' playlists via /channel/lists, but both efforts were a bust as the /channel/list only returned the single top-level channel and the playlists were empty.

Edit #2: I tried the solution from this: [Youtube api get the channels from the Featured channels module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620078/youtube-api-get-the-channels-from-the-featured-channels-module) and it did not work (despite this question being tagged as a duplicate of it).

Comment: what's the question ? it's unclear

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to know if those lists of preferred channels are available via the YouTube API or in a feed that can be consumed.

Comment: I don't think so. This is a special channel on YouTube that shows the YouTube "Preferred" channels and I'm looking for a way to get those 1% & 5% lists without having to scrape the pages. Maybe these big channels lists are setup as "featured" on the backend, but that's not how it appears.

Comment: you right ! i remove :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `channelSections.list` endpoint with the Google Preferred channel id (UCiq_aAkP44mMpRx8VvQiF6w), the preferred channel ids are in the `contentDetails` separated in 1% and 5% groups

Example: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelSections.list?part=contentDetails&channelId=UCiq_aAkP44mMpRx8VvQiF6w&_h=1&