# Retrieve all associated channels for YouTube user

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

The client is a YouTube network with several channels. I need to get the list of these channels so I can display their logos, number of videos, etc.

I don't really know how these channels exactly work to be honest. The channel list is under http://youtube.com/user/(username)/channels, listed as "Featured channels", so I need an endpoint where I can request the list by that username.

I couldn't achieve this after trying multiple API urls, both under v2 and v3.

Comment: When you hit this endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails&forUsername=USERNAME&key=YOUR_API_KEY ... what info is missing from there that you're in need of?

Comment: you can have the featured channel of the channel with YouTube API V3, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/22620078/2274530